# Scanning displayed text on BlackBerry device at runtime

Tags: blackberry, text, mobile, screen, collect

Is it possible to scan all the text that is being displayed on BlackBerry screen at run-time? We have a project that needs to collect the common English wording used in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I do not beleive there is a way. Certainly no API that I've seen documented would allow you to do this. Regardless of the purpose of your program, the ability would be a significant security and privacy issue. Essentially the same answer you have gotten for each other platform.